# Como aplicar cores a uma imagem através de uma paleta de cores sem Flash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Um cliente me perguntou se podia fazer um sistema do tipo. Alguém poderia me indicar uma ideia de como se faz isso sem Flash? Ele tem um copo com um detalhe e os dois objetos receberão cores diferentes selecionáveis numa paleta de cores.

Por onde começar num projeto do gênero?

Answer (score 2):

Depende principalmente da complexidade da imagem e da quantidade de cores na paleta.

Se são cores já pré-estabelecidas, e a imagem do produto tem muitos detalhes, acredito ser mais viável utilizar imagens diferentes do produto, uma p/ cada cor.

Mas existem diversas soluções para aplicar cor programaticamente.

Se a imagem for em vetor dá pra fazer facilmente com SVG e jQuery. Podes exportar, por exemplo, uma imagem do Illustrator em SVG e manipular os elementos com jQuery p/ mudar as cores.

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303757/how-to-change-color-of-an-image-using-jquery) tem um post explicando como fazer isso usando Canvas e JavaScript, com [este exemplo](http://users7.jabry.com/overlord/mug.html) relacionado.

[Este plugin jQuery](http://sandbox.nikorablin.com/productColorizer/) parece bem interessante.

Pra fazer a seleção da cor através de uma paleta, existem vários plugins jQuery.

Comment: Pode ser o que eu preciso:
 http://sandbox.nikorablin.com/productColorizer

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução puramente em JavaScript seria o plugin jsColor (http://jscolor.com/).

Exemplo:

```html
<script src="http://freecms.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/project/WebRoot/js/jscolor/jscolor.js"></script>

<input class="color">
```

Comment: Este sistema me permitiria aplicar qualquer cor a um objeto? Mas como esse objeto receberia esta cor? Em que formato de imagem ele deverá estar?

Comment: @MarcosVinicius Esta interface permite a selecão do valor hexadecimal de uma cor, Marcos - a partir daí você pode aplicar o valor, por exemplo, à propriedade `background-color` do estilo de um elemento.

Comment: Obrigado pelo Fiddle, @Cold !